release 23 is not found in system
i'm coding spring boot and my vscode got this problem
The project was not built due to "release 23 is not found in the system". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent"
I just try to run my application,it's no error detected by debugger and I expexted that it will run successfully

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I think that you're encountering an issue because the JDK version on your computer is lower than JDK 23, which you selected when initializing the Spring Boot project. Try using a lower JDK version in the project, or update your machine to the latest JDK version. Hope this helps!
